# Run Jenkins Job with requirement capabilities match

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can i have a job run on any group of slaves whose capabilities match the Job requirements in jenkins.

This gives lot of flexibility then using node labels, what i am looking for in Jenkins is similar to https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-job-s-requirements-289277064.html

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-Description  - try this plugin we can dynamically associate any node to a job